# The components of applied forces on the masses of a Trebuchet

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, lagrangian-formalism, free-body-diagram

## Background information:

I was following an online mechanics document in order to learn how to derive the equations of motion for a trebuchet (shown below) using Lagrangian mechanics.

[image]

At some point we derived the generalized forces due to **applied forces** in order to derive the equations of motion for the trebuchet that is:

**$\large\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{\partial T}{\partial \dot \theta}) = F_{\theta} + \frac{\partial T}{\partial \theta} $**

Which is the equivalent to:

$\huge\frac{dp_{\theta}}{dt} = F_{\theta} + \frac{\partial T}{\partial \theta}$

*(Where $\theta$ and $\phi$ are the generalized coordinates for the system, **T** is its kinetic energy, and **p** is the generalized momentum)*

The following shows generalized force formula for the system:

$\large F_{\theta} = F_{X} \frac{\partial X}{\partial \theta} + F_{Y} \frac{\partial Y}{\partial \theta} + F_{x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta} + F_{y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta}$

(Where X, Y, *x*, and *y* are Cartesian coordinates for *M* and *m*, respectively)

The gravitational forces for *M* and *m* are **F** = –Mg and **f** = -mg, as shown below.

[image]

Where

> $F_{X} = 0,            F_{Y} = -Mg,        F_{x}= 0 = f_{x},  F_{y}  = f_{y} = -mg$

### The question:

However, in the document, it says that the x-axis components of both the gravitational 
forces **F** and **f** must be equal to zero.

My question is:

**Why the x-axis component of the gravitational forces (weights) are equal to zero?**

Comment: If X and x are horizontal axes, is it not obvious that the vertical gravitational forces F and f will have no horizontal (x) component?

Comment: Related question: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/258952/2451

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gravitational force is (by definition) vertical. If it were not, a horizontally unsupported body would accelerate laterally, and this is not seen. You may be confusing the purely gravitational forces from other, mechanically coupled, forces.